# Detect an invalid timezone with momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

Is there a way I can detect an invalid timezone with momentjs?
If I do this:

```
const m = moment.tz("01/01/2019 5:30pm", "MM/DD/YYYY h:mma", true, "invalid timezone");
m.isValid(); //true
```

Is there any way to make `isValid()` return `false`, or is there some other way to detect that the timezone is invalid?

It logs the following: `Moment Timezone has no data for invalid timezone. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/` but how can I tell programatically?

Comment: check if `m.tz() === undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working with a fully created `Moment` object, then the answer given by Jaromanda X is the way to go.  However, if you're just testing for the time zone name being valid (and loaded into moment), then you don't need to construct a Moment object to do that.  Just test the time zone name itself.

```
if (!moment.tz.zone('FooBarTimeZone')) {
    console.log('Invalid time zone');
} else {
     console.log('Valid time zone');
}
```

Note that this works because the `moment.tz.zone` function returns either a `Zone` object (which like any *object* is truthy), or `null` (which is falsey).

Also note that there was originally a `moment.tz.zoneExists` function, which still works - but will now give a deprecation message, describing using the above technique instead.

Answer (score 1):

check if `m.tz() === undefined`

```js
let m = moment.tz("01/01/2019 5:30pm", "MM/DD/YYYY h:mma", true, "invalid timezone");
console.log(`"invalid timezone" results in .tz() == ${m.tz()}`)

m = moment.tz("01/01/2019 5:30pm", "MM/DD/YYYY h:mma", true, "Australia/Melbourne");
console.log(`"Australia/Melbourne" results in .tz() == ${m.tz()}`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Of course you can also check if a zone exists

```js
console.log(`"invalid zone name is ${moment.tz.zone("invalid zone name")}`);
console.log(`"australia/nsw" is ${JSON.stringify(moment.tz.zone("australia/nsw"), null, 4)}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```